# Tortoise SVN, ignored files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are using TortoiseSVN for our projects.

I know it is possible for me to ignore a file or folder upon committing it by right clicking on it and choosing ignore.

Is it possible to set this up globally so anyone who hooks up to our project will all use the same ignore list?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean SVN, rather than SNV?

Comment: That would be correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ignore a file or folder and makes a commit, the file is marked as ignored file, until you or other partner change the property and make a new commit. and yes this is globally.